# What does MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI] mean and what does it do?

Tags: assembly, x86

Alright so I have this line in my assembly

```
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]
```

where ESI is `00402050` (ascii, "123456789012")

After this instruction: `EAX = 34333231`

What really happened here? How is this value calculated, and why?
Where could I get some good reference on this kind of thing?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Registers in square brackets such as `[ESI]` are dereferenced pointers.  The instruction you quote moves the `DWORD` (a 32-bit/4-byte value) in memory location specified by `ESI` into register `EAX`.  In your case, memory location `00402050`, read as a `DWORD`, contains `34333231`.

Written in pseudo-C:

```
DWORD EAX;   /* Declaring the registers as we find them in silico */
DWORD ESI;

ESI = 0x00402050;  /* Set up your initial conditions for ESI */
EAX = *((DWORD *)ESI);   /* mov EAX, DWORD PTR [ESI] */
/*  ^ ^  ^^^^^^^    */
/*  | |     |       */
/*  | |     +-----------  From "DWORD PTR" we get "DWORD *" in C.          */
/*  | |             */ 
/*  | +-----------------  The C dereferencing operator * replaces [].      */
/*  |               */ 
/*  +-------------------  The C assignment operator = replaces mov opcode. */
```

In your case, it is not true that `0x00402050` "equals" the string `"1234567890"` -- rather it points to the memory which contains that string.

The value which you obtain, `0x34333231` is comprised from the ASCII values for the digits `"1234"`, which are the first four bytes (i.e., the first `DWORD`) of the string.  They appear in reversed order because the Intel architecture is "little endian" in the byte representation of a `DWORD` in memory.

In your example at this time, the `mov` instruction is loading ASCII characters as if they were the four bytes of an `unsigned long` value, when they are actually a string of single-byte characters.

Comment: You should also mention that `DS:[ESI]` notation means that that `ESI` holds an *offset* from address in `DS` (data segment register), so the instruction moves double word (32-bit value) from address `DS + ESI` to register `EAX`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure agree that would be pedagogical at this stage.  In protected mode DS is a selector, not a segment.  I believe OP is in a protected mode because Linux, Windows and MacOS all run in VM-enabled protected mode and OP doesn't seem to be an embedded systems programmer.  Given the complex situation which is actually very simple (DS is mapped to the whole address range and the selector base is zero), why attempt to peel that onion?

Comment: @Nikolai, I am glad it was mentioned here for some 'completeness.'

Comment: I have a question to *((DWORD *)ESI) from the pseudocode. At the beginning you say registers with brackets are dereferenced pointers. So in that line, does the DWORD * ESI is equivalent to something like int *p ?

Comment: Yes, exactly similar.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov That was exactly what I wanted to find out.