# What does FSTP DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+1224] do?

Tags: debugging, assembly, cpu-registers, ollydbg

I am trying to learn more about assembly and disassembly.
My goal is to modify the way a specific address is being written using a debugger (olly). Preferably by incrementing it by a number (20, 50, etc..) I can identify the address of the floating point number (in this case located at `33B7420C`).

When I set a breakpoint on memory access write it brings me to `00809B2E` which has the following assembly:

`FSTP DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+1224]`

What exactly is it doing in this address? I know that the FPU register has the number i'm looking for but not sure what all this address is doing.

The closest I come to googling is:
[What does MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI] mean and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224524/what-does-mov-eax-dword-ptr-dsesi-mean-and-what-does-it-do)

A copy of the registers shows the following:

```
EAX 00000000
ECX 00A16E40 EZ.00A16E40
EDX FFFFFFFF
EBX 33B74578
ESP 0018FA90
EBP 00000000
ESI 33B72FE8
EDI 33B74578
EIP 00809B2E <EZ.Breakpoint for time>
C 0  ES 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
P 0  CS 0023 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
A 0  SS 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
Z 0  DS 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
S 0  FS 0053 32bit 7EFDD000(FFF)
T 0  GS 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
D 0
O 0  LastErr ERROR_SUCCESS (00000000)
EFL 00210202 (NO,NB,NE,A,NS,PO,GE,G)
ST0 valid 1150.0000000000000000
ST1 zero  0.0
ST2 zero  0.0
ST3 empty 64.951911926269531250
ST4 empty -13.250000000000000000
ST5 empty 64.951911926269531250
ST6 empty 64.951911926269531250
ST7 empty 0.0239995196461677551
           3 2 1 0      E S P U O Z D I
FST 2927  Cond 0 0 0 1  Err 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1  (LT)
FCW 027F  Prec NEAR,53  Mask    1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You should get a copy of the x86 assembly reference for explanations of particular instructions. Asking SO each time you encounter an instruction does not scale well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`FSTP` stores a floating point number from the top of the floating-point register stack (`ST0`) to the designated memory region. Using the `DWORD` modifier means that a 32-bit float will be written. The `P` suffix indicates that the floating-point register stack will be popped after the operation.

So, in effect, this instruction puts `1150.0` (as a 32-bit float) at `DS:[ESI+1224]`, then pops the register stack (which causes `ST0 = 0.0`, `ST1 = 0.0`, `ST2 = <empty>`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks like @raymond said, i'll have to read up more on the x86 assembly. I'm trying to add the value of that stack by 50., but I don't know how to achieve this in assembly. Is it load the register and use `FADD` pointing to some memory address that contains 50.? I guess i'll have to read up more on assembly :(

Answer (score 1):

It's storing ST0 (1150.0) in single-precision to your address. And popping said value from the FPU stack.

Answer (score -3):

To add 50 (0x32 being hex for 50):

```
mov eax, dword[ds:esi+0x1224]
add eax, 0x32
mov dword[ds:esi+0x1224], eax
```